# Simplifying iterated sums where the upper bound is the next index

Tags: combinatorics, summation

Consider first the iterated integral $I=m!\int_0^x\int_0^{x_1} ... \int_0^{x_{m-1}} \prod_{i=1}^m dx_i f(x_i)$.

By permuting the dummy indices, we can reorder $x_1$ to $x_m$ to find new expressions for $I$. By adding all of these expressions together and dividing by $m!$, we recover:

$$m!\int_0^x\int_0^{x_1} ... \int_0^{x_{m-1}}\prod_{i=1}^m dx_i f(x_i) = \left(\int_0^x dy f(y)\right)^m.$$

Now consider the sum: $$S = m! \sum_{n_1=0}^n \sum_{n_2=0}^{n_1} ... \sum_{n_m=0}^{n_{m-1}} \prod_{i=1}^m a_{n_i}$$

Using the same tactic used on the integrals for $S$ for the case of $m=2$, I find that
$$2!\sum_{n_1=0}^n \sum_{n_2=0}^{n_1} a_{n_1} a_{n_2} = \left(\sum_{j=0}^n a_j\right)^2 + \left(\sum_{j=0}^n a_j^2\right)$$
so it is clear that there are necessarily extra terms relative to the integral case.

---

How can I simplify the form of $S$? Since the choice of $a_n = 1$ simplifies nicely for general $m$ because of the hockey-stick identity, perhaps there is a straightforward combinatorical path.

Comment: The problem arises when there are equal terms for the sum. For the integral, this can be considered as never happening, but this doesn't work for the sum. For higher $m$, I think it would get increasingly complicated.

Comment: I've answered the question of expressing $S$ in terms of sums of powers of $a$'s. If your question is rather a matter of *computation*, there's a (probably) better dynamic-programming-style approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expressing $S_m$ in terms of $P_m$ where, for $a_0,\ldots,a_n$ considered fixed, $$S_m:=\sum_{0\leqslant k_1\leqslant\ldots\leqslant k_m\leqslant n}\prod_{j=1}^m a_{k_j},\qquad P_m:=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k^m,$$ can be done using generating functions. With $S_0:=1$, we have $$\sum_{m=0}^\infty S_m z^m=\prod_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{1-a_k z}=\exp\sum_{k=0}^n\big(-\log(1-a_k z)\big)=\exp\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{P_m}{m}z^m,$$ which gives the following formula: $$S_m=\sum_{\substack{n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_m\geqslant 0\\n_1+2n_2+\ldots+mn_m=m}}\prod_{k=1}^m\frac{(P_k/k)^{m_k}}{m_k!}.\tag{*}\label{result}$$

Here are particular cases, continuing yours:
\begin{align*}
  1!S_1&=P_1
\\\color{blue}{2!S_2}&=\color{blue}{P_1^2+P_2}
\\3!S_3&=P_1^3+3P_1P_2+2P_3
\\4!S_4&=P_1^4+6P_1^2P_2+3P_2^2+8P_1P_3+6P_4
\\5!S_5&=P_1^5+10P_1^3P_2+15P_1P_2^2+20P_1^2P_3+20P_2P_3+30P_1P_4+24P_5
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Staring at the coefficients has made me recognize that the coefficients are multinomial numbers. See also the first formula of http://oeis.org/A036039, which I believe shows the multinomial result directly from your formula for $S_m$. If you add the multinomial form of the coefficients to your answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Also, the simplification in terms of multinomial numbers might also help simplify your question and answer in MSE 3232079.

Comment: @user196574: Thank you for the (reference to the) OEIS entry. I was looking for a purely combinatorial approach as well (the polynomial we end up with is the [cycle index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_index#Symmetric_group_Sn) of the full symmetric group, so $\eqref{result}$ is just an application of [Pólya enumeration theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya_enumeration_theorem#Full,_weighted_version)). Still I don't get what you call "the multinomial form". Isn't $\eqref{result}$ in this form already?

Comment: @user196574: Anyway I'm going to edit these details in. As for the [mentioned Q&A](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3232079), if you see an *alternative* answer (bypassing the generating function), you're free to post it there ;)

Comment: After looking around, yours is definitely the usual multinomial form. I've come across them in a different form in a different context, but yours is the most explicit form, so I won't belabor that! As for the question of an alternative answer to the Q&A, I think I'll at least leave a comment today or tomorrow :)