# Tight upper bound on $\sum_{j=1}^{n}(-1)^{j-1}{n \choose j}\frac{1}{j}$?

Tags: inequality, summation, solution-verification, binomial-coefficients, harmonic-numbers

I would like to prove the following inequality (upper bound):

\begin{align}
\xi(n) = \sum_{j=1}^{n}(-1)^{j-1}{n \choose j}\frac{1}{j} \leq 3\ln(n),
\end{align}

for $n\geq 2$. I have made an attempt to prove this using induction, i.e.

$(n=2):$
\begin{align}
(-1)^{0}{2 \choose 1}\frac{1}{1} + (-1)^{1}{2 \choose 2}\frac{1}{2} = \frac{3}{2} \leq 3\ln(2). 
\end{align}

Assume $(n)$ holds and show $(n+1)$ holds:
\begin{align}
\xi(n+1) = \sum_{j=1}^{n+1}(-1)^{j-1}{n+1 \choose j}\frac{1}{j} &= (-1)^n\frac{1}{n+1} + \sum_{j=1}^{n}(-1)^{j-1}{n+1 \choose j}\frac{1}{j}\\
&= (-1)^n\frac{1}{n+1} + \sum_{j=1}^{n}(-1)^{j-1}\left[{n\choose j}+{n \choose j-1}\right]\frac{1}{j}\\
&= (-1)^n\frac{1}{n+1} + \sum_{j=1}^{n}(-1)^{j-1}{n\choose j}\frac{1}{j} + \sum_{j=1}^{n}(-1)^{j-1}{n \choose j-1}\frac{1}{j}.\\
&= (-1)^n\frac{1}{n+1} + \xi(n) + \sum_{j=1}^{n}(-1)^{j-1}{n \choose j-1}\frac{1}{j}.\\
\end{align}

Now I cannot figure out how
\begin{align}
(-1)^n\frac{1}{n+1} + \sum_{j=1}^{n}(-1)^{j-1}{n \choose j-1}\frac{1}{j} \leq 3\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right).
\end{align}

Which is the missing part in this proof. Maybe I am on the wrong track. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Are you aware of the identity $\xi(n)=H_n$? It simplifies things considerably.

Comment: No I was not aware of that. Thank you for pointing this out. I can see how this simplifies things.

Comment: [Proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Calculation) on Wikipedia. Linking to my ["hub" question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3232079).

Comment: @metamorphy Thanks a lot for your links they helped a lot to see the whole picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed a totally different path. Hope it helps, anyway.
$$\sum _{j=1}^n \frac{(-1)^{j-1} \binom{n}{j}}{j}=H_n=\psi (n+1)+\gamma$$

where $\gamma$ is Euler-Mascheroni constant and $\psi$ is digamma function

as $n\to\infty$
$$\psi (n+1)+\gamma=\ln n+\gamma +\frac{1}{2 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\le 1+\ln n$$

As $\gamma +\frac{1}{2 n}<1.1$

Comment: It is known that $$
H_n  < \log n + \gamma  + \frac{1}{{2n}}
$$
for all $n\geq 1$.

Comment: @Gary Yep! I edited my answer. Actually $H_n<1.1+\log n$

Comment: Note that $$
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{k}}  = 1 + \sum\limits_{k = 2}^n {\frac{1}{k}}  < 1 + \sum\limits_{k = 2}^n {\int_{k - 1}^k {\frac{{dt}}{t}} }  = 1 + \int_1^n {\frac{{dt}}{t}}  = 1 + \log n
$$
for all $n\geq 1$.

Comment: @Gary Actually for $n=1$ they are both $1$